# reload page I lose all values in form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have made a web form that has some fields that are manually entered, others that are a dropdown, and some calendar fields that are in javascript.  My latest addition has a dropdown that is populated from a selected value of a previous dropdown.  When it reloads the form, I lose all of the previously entered values and only retains the value to the one dropdown.  Do I have to capture all the values, or is there a way to just populate the 2nd dropdown without reloading the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-.- one word. AJAX. use it.

any time you reload a form you will lose all unrecorded data period.

If you must reload the page save all the data in a cookie or something.

Comment: I've resisted AJAX on this entire form, but I think it's my only option.  I'm going to have to learn it.

Comment: Theres no point in resisting ajax. most users hate forms that submit with refreshing the page. suck it up.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to save data without ajax and whithout sending anything to the server. It's called sessionStorage.

```
// store item
localStorage.setItem("index", "value");

// retrieve item
var data = localStorage.getItem("index");
```

So you just have to save the datas with sessionStorage after any action (click on a button, keydown, mouseleave…) and whe you reload the page, you just have to populate it again from the data you have stored in session!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by reloading the form you mean submitting it, which then returns a version of the page with the second dropdown populated according to the submitted first dropdown. If that's the case, you might consider having all possible values of the second dropdown hidden and then populating it with JavaScript after a selection in the first one is made. If the amount of possible values is very big or has to be computed server side (as in, you cannot know all the values initially) then you could use AJAX to submit the form and avoid reloading of the entire page.

Comment: No, I actually meant reload page, which now that you said this, makes me realize reloading the page, re initializes everything, so wouldn't have solved my problem anyways.  I going to look at adapting ajax to my form.

Answer (score 0):

Check your page's `cache-control`. This attribute tells the browser to rely on its own cache to reload pages.

This can be set as a meta tag. For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
```

But a better approach (in my opinion) is through the server-side, using the `header()`[function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Note that some prefer to set it to `no-cache` when it comes to forms, in order to avoid spam and also for security reasons.